Why can we set $\Phi_{fv} = 0$ as the limit when $\rho$ tends to infinity?
On Pg.14 of Dine, Leigh, et al's Towards The Theory Of The Electro-Weak Phase Transition, they reduce the 3-dimensional instanton equation to: $$\frac{d^2 \phi}{d \rho^2} + \frac{2}{\rho}\frac{d\phi}{d \rho} = V'(\phi).$$ With the boundary condition that $\frac{d \phi}{d \rho}|_{0} = 0$ which is necessary to avoid a singularity at the origin, and that $\phi$ tends to 0 as $\rho$ tends to infinity. In other papers, most notably S. Coleman's Fate Of The False Vacuum, they simply have $\phi$ tend to some constant false vacuum as $\rho$ tends to infinity. Why can we set the false vacuum to zero? Is this an arbitrary choice in the same way we can set a standard potential equal to 0 and get the same results in classical physics?
